# Can we NOT set nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-timeout: '120' using ingress annotations?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

The default value of said annotation is 60 sec; I am looking to change its value to 120 sec. I added this as an annotation in ingress resource file but it doesn't seem to be working.

Since my request body is quite big, I am getting 408 from ingress http server immediately after 60 sec only;

Where else I can define this annotation if it is not allowed in ingress file itself?

The following page doesn't mention this annotation; Is it because it is not meant to be added as an annotation?

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations

Ingress resource snippet:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /my-app
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-header-buffer-size: "1M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-header-timeout: "60"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "1M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-timeout: "120"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        proxy_set_header custom-header $1;
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(UK)/my-app/(.*)$
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Where did you get this annotation from if not from official documentation?

Comment: I got it from this page: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/
Can I not set this as an annotation?

Comment: Can you post the actual resource you used?

Comment: The option you mentioned is supposed to be set in nginx configmap (global configuration). Check `kubectl get deployments.apps -n kube-system nginx-ingress-controller -oyaml | grep -- --configmap` for a hint on how your configmap is called. In your case kubectl command may look a bit different.

Comment: David, I have added the content of my ingress resource to my question.

Comment: HelloWorld, Are you saying what we can define in config map can not be defined in ingress annotations?

Comment: I think that this may be the case but I need to confirm it.

Comment: HelloWorld, Following link rules out your assumption:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/#configmap-and-ingress-annotations

Comment: Please don't mix nginx ingress controller provided by [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/kubernetes-ingress-controller/) and other provided by [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). These are two different things.

Comment: Ok, but isn't Kubernetes supports nginx controllers? I mean doesn't it support all features provided by Nginx ingress controller?

Comment: One nginx controller is maintained by kubernetes community and the other one by nginx (the company behind nginx product). Here is the github repo for [Nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) and [kubernetes nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

Comment: I have found that Nginx controller provided by kubernetes community doesn't provide annotation [here is a link to github repo with annotations code](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/internal/ingress/annotations) that you are interested in. This means that what you are left with is either setting this option globally or opening feature request on github and waiting for someone to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize our conversation in comments:

There are two Nginx ingress controllers;
One nginx controller is maintained by kubernetes community and the other one by nginx (the company behind nginx product). Here is the github repo for [Nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) and and here for [kubernetes nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx).

---

Nginx controller provided by kubernetes doesn't allow setting `client-body-timeout` with annotation. Here is a [link to github repo with annotations code](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/internal/ingress/annotations). This means that what you are left with is either

- setting this parameter globally, or
- opening feature request on github and waiting for someone to implement it.

`client-body-timeout` parameter can only be set through global config (as specified in [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/)).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to HelloWorlds answer, if someone is looking to provide this annotation globally with Kubernetes version of Ingress then following steps could be followed:

1. Check in which namespace ingress pod is running. Mostly the namespace name will be something like *-ingress-some-string-*.

   $ kubectl get ns

   Lets say the namespace is: 'ingress-nginx'
2. Now that namespace is known, check pods inside that namespace.

   $ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx

   Lets say you get a pod something like: 'ingress-nginx-controller-abcdefg'
3. Check the configmap this pod is using the following command:

   $ kubectl get pod ingress-nginx-controller-abcdefg -n ingress-nginx -o yaml | grep configmap

   You will get an output something like: --configmap=${POD_NAMESPACE}/nginx-configuration
4. Now, you have to create a config map with above name with required and supported configurations by Kubernetes Ingress.

   $ cat global-configmap.yaml

   ---

   apiVersion: v1

   kind: ConfigMap

   meta:

   ```
    name: nginx-configuration

    namespace: ingress-nginx
   ```

   data:

   ```
    client-body-timeout: "120"   # default value is 60 seconds
   ```
5. Now, apply this config map yaml.

   $ kubectl apply -f global-configmap.yaml